# Let $1,2,3$ be possible values of a random variable $X$. Knowing that $EX=2.3$ and $EX^2=5.9$, how can I find P(X=1)?

Tags: probability

Let $1,2,3$ be possible values of a discrete random variable $X$. Knowing that $EX=2.3$ and $EX^2=5.9$, how can I find $P(X=1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p_i = p(i)$. Solve the following system of three linear equations
$$p_1 + p_2 + p_3 = 1$$
$$p_1 + 2p_2 + 3p_3 = 2.3$$
$$p_1 + 4 p_2 + 9p_3 = 5.9$$